# Add sortable list into empty list and remove sortable list without duplication

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

In the code below, i have an empty list and 2 sortable list for a user to use. The user can sort the buttons within the list and add buttons to the empty list or remove them once added. I am able to add the buttons from the list to the empty list but not being able to understand how to stop the same list item from being duplicated in the empty list when the add button is clicked again or how to remove them once the empty list is filled. Any help would be appreciated  :)

HTML -

```
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

    <style>
        .modal-body ul {
            list-style-type: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<ul id="dynamic-list" class="link col-lg-12 sub-menu-center" aria-expanded="false" style="text-align: center; float: left">
<li>Append Sorted List here from current tab </li>


</ul>
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title mt-0" id="addFeatures"> ADD BUTTTONS</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
           <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 ">
            <h6 style="text-align: left; font-weight: bold;">CURRENT</h6>
            <div class="col-lg-12" style="border: 1px solid grey;height: 100%;text-align: center">
                 &nbsp;
            <ul class="existing" style="min-height:100px">
                  <?php 
                features();
                ?>
                  
            </ul>  
            </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-lg-6 ">
                <h6 style="text-align: left; font-weight: bold;">AVAILABLE</h6>
                
                <div class="col-lg-12" style="border: 1px solid grey; height: 100%;text-align: center">
                    &nbsp;
                    <ul id="available" class="available" style="min-height:100px" >
                        <li id="createwindow"><button class="col-lg-12 btn btn-dark" type="button" onclick="createWindow()">Button1</button></li>
                        <li id="createsource"><button class="col-lg-12 btn btn-dark" type="button">Button2</button></li>
                        <li id="createencoder"><button class="col-lg-12 btn btn-dark" type="button" >Button3</button></li>
                        
                        <li id="createschedule"><button class="col-lg-12 btn btn-dark" type="button">Button4</button></li>  
                        
                        <li id="createlayout"><button class="col-lg-12 btn btn-dark" type="button">Button5</button></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
               </div>
        </div>
            &nbsp;
        <div class="modal-footer" style="">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" onclick="addFeatures()" data-dismiss="modal">Add</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT -

```
 $('.existing').sortable({
        handle: 'button',
        cancel: '',
        connectWith:'.available',
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
          dropOnEmpty: true
    });
})

$(function () {
    $('.available').sortable({
        handle: 'button',
        cancel: '',
        connectWith: '.existing',
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
          dropOnEmpty: true
    });
})

function addFeatures (){    
    var list_location = document.getElementById ('dynamic-list');
    var ul = document.querySelectorAll ('.existing li');
    
    for (let i = 0; i <= ul.length; i++) {
        $( ul[i] ).clone().appendTo(list_location);
    }
}
```

Unordered list with `id="dynamic-list"` is the empty list that user adds buttons to.
Unordered list with `id="existing"` and `id="available"` are sortable lists.

Heres a Fiddle of the code - [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/40yx67ua/25/)

Comment: simply empty dynamic-list before appending `lis` i.e : `$("#dynamic-list").empty()`